# Is it possible to use ASG with multiple instance types and different disk size?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

So I`m using auto-scailing ASG with multiple instance types.
I would like to allocate different disk size depends on the instance type...
Is it possible?

thanks

Comment: You cannot pk=lay with disk size but cpu's and memory definitely https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ec2-auto-scaling-mixed-instances-groups-instance-weighting.html

Comment: if you dont mind I would like to answer my comment as answer if it helped you so that it may help other in the future